# Bottle and mod_wsgi "exit signal Segmentation fault (11)"

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, bottle, eel

Tried to launch my bottle app in my apache, mod_wsgi docker container but I have these errors :

`exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`

My httpd.conf :

```
Transferlog /dev/stdout
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonPath /usr/lib/python3.6
Alias / /srv/
<Directory /srv>
    Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "mywebsite.com"

    WSGIDaemonProcess eel user=apache group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/app.wsgi

    <Directory /srv>
        WSGIProcessGroup eel
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

App.wsgi :

```
# Change working directory so relative paths (and template lookup) work again
os.chdir('/srv/')

import bottle
# ... build or import your bottle application here ...
# Do NOT use bottle.run() with mod_wsgi
import eel

"eel app"

eel.init("Web")
eel.start("index.html", host='0.0.0.0', mode='False')
```

I don't knwo what is wrong with my config and I didn't find much info on the web

If someone can help me with that...

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Probably unrelated to your segfault, but you want `mode=False`, not `mode='False'`.

Comment: The string `"eel app"` is doing nothing. Why is it there?

Comment: Why are you importing `bottle` but not using it anywhere?

Comment: The eel app string represent my eel app it was to make the script smaller for the forum, it's all of my @eel.expose calls